# How do I take one object array and combine two data points into one?

Tags: json, underscore.js

I have the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "LicenseeID": "665",
        "FirstName": "Stephen",
        "LastName": "Durham"
    }, {
        "LicenseeID": "666",
        "FirstName": "Brandon",
        "LastName": "Durham"
    }
]
```

How do I combine the `FirstName` and `LastName` fields into one, like this:

```
[
    {
        "LicenseeID": "665",
        "Name": "Stephen Durham"
    }, {
        "LicenseeID": "666",
        "Name": "Brandon Durham"
    }
]
```

This is for a Backbone/Underscore project, so I have all relative utilities available (like Underscore's `_.map` function).

Thank you!

Comment: `function(olditem){ return {LicenseeID:item.LicenseeID, Name:item.FirstName+" "+item.LastName}; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
_(licensees).map(function(licensee){ 
    licensee['Name'] = licensee.FirstName + ' ' + licensee.LastName;
    return licensee;
});
```